# Entidades podem passar de um caso de uso para outro usando o controlador?

Tags: typescript, arquitetura-de-software

Estou trabalhando em um projeto com a tarefa de criar uma rota para realizar o checkout de compras de ingressos para eventos. Nesse cenário, tenho um controlador que recebe a solicitação com os dados do pedido, informações do cliente, ingressos e detalhes do pagamento. Posteriormente, passo essa solicitação para meus casos de uso para executar as tarefas.

No entanto, tenho um caso de uso onde crio um Order, que é uma entidade, e preciso que outro caso de uso receba Order para validar os ingressos usando a entidade Tickets. Mais tarde, se a validação for bem-sucedida, Orders é passado para o caso de uso de pagamento, criando a entidade Transaction. Tudo isso é feito no mesmo controlador, de forma semelhante ao código abaixo:

```
    export class CheckoutController implements Controller {
    
      constructor(
       private createOrder: CreateOrder,
       private makeTicketValidate: MakeTicketValidate,
       private makePayment: MakePayment,
       ){}
    
      async handle (request: CheckoutController.Request): Promise<HttpResponse> {
    
         const order: Order = this.createOrder(request)
         // Aqui eu recebo a entidade Order e passo para o próximo caso de uso
    
         const isValid: boolean = await this.makeTicketValidate(order)
    
         if(!isValid) {
           return badRequest()
         }
         
         const transactionId = await this.makePayment(order)
    
         if(!transactionId) {
           return internalServerError()
         }
        
         return ok({transactionId})
         
      }
    }
```

É possível que eu esteja violando algum princípio da arquitetura limpa neste controlador?

Passar a entidade Pedido pelo controlador de um caso de uso para outro é um mau cheiro de código?

Está correto ter múltiplos casos de uso no mesmo controlador? Especialmente considerando quando uma grande quantidade de dados é processada em uma única ação? Ou devo separá-los em controladores separados?

Eu preciso retornar dados através de um apresentador, ou posso simplesmente usar o retorno do próprio caso de uso no controlador para enviar a resposta HTTP para o frontend?

Agradeço antecipadamente a todos que responderem!

Tenho considerado usar um objeto de acesso a dados para a entidade 'Pedido' para transferir dados entre os casos de uso.

Alternativamente, eu poderia separar os controladores para dividir as responsabilidades.

Comment: Não, sua abordagem não viola os princípios da Arquitetura Limpa se as entidades representam claramente as regras de negócio e se mantêm desacopladas de frameworks externos. Ter múltiplos casos de uso num único controlador é aceitável para operações relacionadas, mas cuidado com o acoplamento e a complexidade. Use padrões como Mediator para desacoplar casos de uso e manter a flexibilidade.

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu comentário, obrigado pela dica do design pattern vou estudar como aplica-lo nesse código!